# Rails - Removing 'data-confirm' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dialog, custom-data-attribute

Rails uses unobtrusive javascript to prompt confirm messages on a (submit) button. These messages are stored in a `data-confirm` attribute on the button/link.

Now, suppose you only want to confirm sometimes, as in my case where I only want to prompt when busy editing prices, you obviously add and remove these attributes with javascript (jQuery)

```
$('.create-order').attr('data-confirm', "Warning: You are busy editing item prices and you haven't applied your changes yet. Continue?");
```

and

```
$('.create-order').removeAttr('data-confirm');
```

This is working and the attribute is **definitely** being appended and removed ( I double checked). But I noticed that once the message has been displayed once, it will display every time after that as well, even after the attribute has been removed. ( I invite anyone to try this as well and share your results? )

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: In this case I would rather do my own implementation of confirm messages and show them exactly when I want. Overriding javascript Rails uses like this can be problematic without looking at the implementation, as you found out, and the implementation might change in the future versions and mess up your application again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would override the **confirm** method from jquery_ujs.js file as following :

```
$.rails.confirm  = function(message){
 //your logic here : must return true or false, you can call js default confirm method
}
```

Comment: Maybe this link can help you : http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2012/07/18/customizing-confirmation-dialog-in-rails/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I deal with it (seems to be simplier) :

Rails form :

```
<%= @form_for(@obj) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :attribute %><br />
    <%= f.radio_button :my_radio, false %> Finished <%= f.radio_button :my_radio, true %> Not yet !<br />
    <%= f.submit id: "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

And Jquery :

```
<script>
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        if ($("#my_radio_false").is(':checked')) {
            return confirm("Are-you sure ?");
            return true;
        }
    });
</script>
```

You can test it here :

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  if ($("#my_radio_false").is(':checked')) {
    return confirm("Are you sure ?");
    return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" /><br />
  <input value="true" name="analysis[is_analysed]" id="my_radio_true" type="radio"> Finished 
  <input value="false" name="analysis[is_analysed]" id="my_radio_false" type="radio" checked="checked"> Not Yet !<br />
  <input name="commit" value="Test it !" id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Hope that helps